# Using the generalised mean value theorem to justify an application of the dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the book "Conditional Monte Carlo - Gradient Estimation and Optimization Applications". The book covers the stochastic gradient estimation problem where we would like to estimate

$$
\frac{d\mathbb{E}_{\omega \sim \mu}[L(\theta; \omega)]}{d\theta}
$$

where $L$ is some random variable parameterised by $\theta$, and $\omega$ is an element of the underlying sample space $\Omega$. The authors suggest the following estimator:

$$
\frac{dL(\theta; \omega)}{d\theta} = \lim_{\Delta\theta \to 0}\frac{L(\theta + \Delta\theta; \omega) - L(\theta; \omega)}{\Delta\theta}
$$

One property of interest is unbiasedness. That is we'd like

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{dL(\theta; \omega)}{d\theta}\right] = \frac{d\mathbb{E}[L(\theta; \omega)]}{d\theta}
$$

For this to hold we must be able to interchange the expectation with the derivative operator. The authors suggests the use of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

> **Theorem $1.1$ Dominated Convergence Theorem.** If $\lim_{\Delta\theta \to 0} g_{\Delta \theta} = g$  w.p.1, and $\exists \epsilon > 0$ s.t. |$g_{\Delta \theta}| \leq K$ w.p.1 $\forall \Delta\theta \in [0,\epsilon]$ with $E[K] < \infty$ and $K$ independent of $\theta$, then $\lim_{\Delta \theta \to 0} E[g_{\Delta \theta}] = E[g].$

The intuition being that we take

$$
g_{\Delta\theta} = \frac{L(\theta + \Delta\theta; \omega) - L(\theta; \omega)}{\Delta\theta}
$$

However to apply the DCT, we need an upper bound $K$ (which is also a random variable) with finite expectation. The authors suggest the use of the generalised mean value theorem to establish this bound.

> **Theorem $1.2$ Generalized Mean Value Theorem.** Let $L$ be a continuous function that is differentiable on $\tilde{\Theta} = \Theta \setminus \tilde{D}$, where $\tilde{D}$ is a set of measure zero. Then, $\forall \theta, \theta + \Delta \theta \in \Theta$,
>
> $$\left | \frac{L(\theta + \Delta \theta) - L(\theta)}{\Delta \theta} \right | \leq \textstyle \sup_{\theta \in \tilde{\Theta}} \left | \frac{\mathrm d L}{\mathrm d \theta} \right |.$$

I assume the logic here is to set $K(\omega) = \sup_{\theta \in \tilde{\Theta}}\left|\frac{dL(\theta; \omega)}{d\theta}\right|$. The authors then make the following claim:

> Thus, if $L(\Theta)$ can be shown to be continuous and piecewise differentiable on $\Theta$ w.p.1, the continuity of $L(\Theta)$ automatically satisfies the boundedness condition required for unbiasedness via the dominated convergence theorem.

For those curious, this argument can be found in Chapter $1$ of the aforementioned book in the section "Basic Theoretical Tools".

---

**My question is as follows**: Is the MVT actually enough to ensure that $\mathbb{E}[K] < \infty$? My feeling is that a slightly stronger condition is needed such as requiring that $L$ is Lipschitz continuous in $\theta$ for any fixed $\omega$ and that the Lipschitz constant is bounded above by some finite value $C$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: Weird notation. What does $E_{\mu \sim \omega}[.]$ mean?

Comment: In the first line, I am trying to write the expectation of the random variable $L(\theta)$ with respect to the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users of the site have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Thanks I will try to!